# Behaviour of verb that looks pronominal but doesn't have a "se" entry in the dictionary?

Tags: grammaire, verbes-pronominaux, auxiliaires, temps-composés

Suppose I want to translate "I pinched myself".
I see that "to pinch" in French is ["pincer"](https://www.wordreference.com/fren/pincer) , and that there (more or less) isn't a "se pincer" entry.

I know that a typical pronominal verb, such as "se demander", uses être instead of avoir when in the passé composé. So, "Je me suis demandé" is correct, and "Je m'ai demandé" is incorrect.

So, "I pinch myself" would be translated by "Je me pince".
But, since there is no "se pincer" entry in the dictionary, I'm not sure which of these two is correct: "Je me suis pincé", or "Je m'ai pincé"?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

All verbs that use the reflexive pronoun are pronominal, and all use *être* for the auxiliary in compound tenses.

Ad-hoc pronominals like *se pincer* can be formed with pretty much any transitive verb and function the same grammatically.

The reason a pronominal verb appears in the dictionary is usually that its meaning is not completely transparent given the meaning of the base verb, or it has an idiomatic sense on top of the literal one. So it's a semantic distinction, not a grammatical one.

Comment: Regardless of the existence of the verb in the french dictionary in its pronominal form, you could use it with a reflexive pronoun in most cases. For example, "I eat myself" (don't do this at home kids) would be "Je me mange" which is grammatically correct, although you won't find "se manger" anywhere in the dictionary.

Comment: @Oddrigue C'est ce que j'ai dit

Answer (score 7):

It's *je me suis pincé*. As soon as you use a reflexive pronoun, it has to follow the normal conjugation rules.

Comment: As opposed to "je m'ai pincé" which would not be *normal*? It may improve the answer to remind the actual rules at play, as Luke did.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the already existing excellent answers, maybe does your confusion come from the definition of pronominal.

Pronominal doesn't just mean that a pronoun is used along the verb, but that this pronoun represent the subject (i.e. is a reflexive pronoun).

When it is not the case, the pronoun is just a regular complement and the auxiliary is *avoir* with most verbs, including *pincer* and *demander*:

> J'ai pincé "toi" → Je t'**ai** pincé.
>
> J'ai demandé "à vous" → Je vous **ai** demandé.

On the other hand, when the pronoun is also the subject, only *être* can be used:

> J'ai pincé "moi" → Je me **suis** pincé.
>
> Vous avez demandé "à vous" → Vous vous **êtes** demandé.